# How do I save value in my own session variable in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, session

I am using Magento and trying to save a value in the session as follows in its index.php file, but the value is not being retained.

```
$_SESSION['myvar'] = '1';
```

How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue when using `setcookie()` directly, as the `core/cookie` model handles setting those, and found it was overwriting my values.

Answer (score 81):

Let's say you want to save the value "Hello world" to the "welcome message" variable in the session. The code would be :

```
$inputMessage = 'Hello World';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setWelcomeMessage($inputMessage);
```

Now you want to echo the "welcome message" somewhere else in your code/site.

```
$outputMessage = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getWelcomeMessage();
echo $this->__($outputMessage);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning how to clear (unset) a session variable:
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsWelcomeMessage();
The "uns" stands for unset.

Comment: I know it was 5 years ago, but THANK YOU!

Answer (score 37):

Following the example given by Ali Nasrullah, I would do:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
// set data
$session->setData("device_id", 4);
// get data
$myDeviceId = $session->getData("device_id");
```

Make sure you include [Mage-root]/app/Mage.php befor calling the code above!

@Ali Nasrullah: Pass the value of device:id as second parameter of the setData function.

Comment: I tried the above but couldn't get it to work. How to call /app/Mage.php. By default, index.php includes: require_once $mageFilename; Is that enough?

Answer (score 13):

```
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMySessionVariable('MyValue'); 

  $myValue  =  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMySessionVariable();

  echo $myValue;

 Take Look For More:
```

[**Here are code to Get, Set, and Unset Session in Magento**](http://jyotiranjan.in/blog/how-set-get-unsetsession-in-magento/)

[Here are code to Get, Set, and Unset Session in Magento](http://jyotiloppy.blogspot.in/2013/10/here-are-code-to-getset-and-unset.html)

Answer (score 8):

```
frontend: Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setYourNameSession($session_value);

backend: Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setYourNameSession($session_value);
```