# Magento session data cache

Tags: magento, session, caching, message

I created session message using this example:

[How do I save value in my own session variable in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340982/how-do-i-save-value-in-my-own-session-variable-in-magento)

This is my code:

//this is called in observer

```
$inputMessage = 'Hello ' . $customerName;
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setWelcomeMessage($inputMessage);
```

this is called in header template

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getWelcomeMessage();
```

I have issue when customer logs-out and cache is enabled - getWelcomeMessage() outputs cached $inputMessage value;

Is there any way to disable cache only for WelcomeMessage? I am using Magento EE 1.11

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have FPC enabled.

I suggest you to first disable FPC and check if this issue is still there or not.

If its gone then use FPC related exclude cache trick check this URL:
[How do I include a dynamic block in the product page with full page caching turned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120413/how-do-i-include-a-dynamic-block-in-the-product-page-with-full-page-caching-turn/9125519#9125519)