# How to create function in magento for setSession data and getSession dat

Tags: php, magento

I need to create function in magento for set session data and getSession data ...
I created on e but this is not working ..

```
public function mySession($data){

        $_session = Mage::getModel('core/session');

        $_session->set($data);

        }
```

how can we write session function for set and gat

Comment: you can reffer this  link [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340982/how-do-i-save-value-in-my-own-session-variable-in-magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your function like

```
    public function mySession($custom_variable, $data){
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData($custom_variable, $data);
        }  
   public function getMySession($custom_variable){  
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData($custom_variable);
        }
```