# Identify Magento visitor before login and after login

Tags: magento, session, authentication, identify

how can i identify visitor in magento which isnt logged in , then he do some action and then he log in / create new account ?

i need to identify that it is the same user, but if i use classic php
session_id()  - this is changed after user logs in.

i tried to get info from

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
```

but there isnt any information about some session id.

any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Could you store a flag in `core/session` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add arbitrary data to a session which you could later read from.  You should reference [How do I save value in my own session variable in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340982/how-do-i-save-value-in-my-own-session-variable-in-magento).

You are correct in that the session id gets updated each time there is a privilege change for the user to help prevent privilege escalation via session fixation.